# chieffancypants loading bar position

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar, navbar

In angular js application, I am using [chieffancypants loading bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar)

I am using bootstrap 3.3.5  navbar-fixed-top. I want to show the loading bar below the navbar,  loading bar is positioned by default on top of the page.
I tried to override the top position in CSS as below, but it doesn't work.

```
#loading-bar .bar {
  -webkit-transition: width 350ms;
  -moz-transition: width 350ms;
  -o-transition: width 350ms;
  transition: width 350ms;

  background: #29d;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  top: 60;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
}
```

Comment: `top: 60` should be `top: 60px`

Comment: so stupid of me, that worked, thanks @JoshWarren

Comment: @JoshWarren if you can add that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top value is missing `px`, so:

`top: 60` should be `top: 60px`